# sql query to return output with the help of join or subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

```
Table1                               Table2
id     Name                     id   table1id      Name
1       A                        1     1            a
2       B                        2     1            aa
3       C                        3     1            aaa
                                 4     2            b
                                 5     2            bb
```

I want output as
Name1     Name2

```
A          a
           aa
           aaa
B          b
           bb
```

Comment: it gave me output which was repeating A thrice but i want only single A

Comment: You know, you should really do your formatting in the front end.

Comment: cant i do it through sql because i am using datalist for the output

Comment: You could format the cells in the datalist.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
Declare @Table1 table
(id int ,name varchar(10))

Insert into @Table1
values
(1,'A' ),
(2,'B'),
(3,'C' )


Declare @Table2 table
(id int,tableid int ,name varchar(10))

Insert into @Table2
values
(2, 1,'aa'),
(3, 1,'aaa'),
(4, 2 ,'b'),
(5,2,'bb')


;With cte(Name1,Name2,rn) as
(Select t1.name ,t2.name,
  row_number() over ( partition by t1.name order by  t1.id) as rn 
  from @table1 as t1 inner join @Table2 as T2
  on t2.tableid=t1.id
)
Select case when rn=1 then name1 else '' end as c1,
name2
from cte
```

Comment: You could remove second SELECT in OVER() clause and use instead order by t1.id.

Comment: Thanks . I was actually trying for Select 0. Didn't notice a column for sorting